# What is the difference between SAP Fiori and Movilizer?

Tags: sap-fiori, movilizer

What is the difference between SAP Fiori and Movilizer?
They both are used to show SAP data in mobile phone, then where is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Fiori- Rich UI design which have a capability to adopt all the platform and have an easy way to develop complex sap business logic

Movilizer-A product from Honeywell, which have an offline and cloud integration to collect data from enterprise (SAP, MS, Oracle) to Mobile app

Regards,
Karthik A

Answer (score 0):

The way I understood it:
Fiori: web based apps
Mobilizer: Hybrid apps

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still looking for an answer but:

1. SAP Fiori: A collection of applications written using the SAPUI5
   framework and Fiori x.0 guidelines. Applications can be
   containerized for use on mobile devices in addition to browsers. ([Link](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi3uvKr4MbSAhUXOsAKHXbxAFQQFgghMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sap.com%2Fproduct%2Ftechnology-platform%2Ffiori.html&usg=AFQjCNEgnIeCF-Myjbn83LsSQ8BpLSex9A&bvm=bv.148747831,d.ZGg))
2. SAP Mobilizer: A Java-based platform with applications for Banking,
   Mobile Money, Wallet etc. The platform provides a mobile enabled app for mobile money, wallet, account management etc. alongside a customer portal.
3. Honeywell Movilizer: A field - orchestration product for managing
   equipment. I'm not sure of their mobile offerings. ([Link](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwith_zU3sbSAhVDL8AKHZppDc8QFggjMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmovilizer.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNGWlUM0K2uzdA7P07rJSsXgX0QLjw))

You might also want to look up SAP Mobile Platform 3.x ([Link](https://www.sap.com/product/technology-platform/mobile-app-development-platform.html))

Hope that helps.